# How we call fragment in MyFirebaseMessagingService in Send Notification method?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I want to call fragment from send notification method in firebase

```
 private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        DataManager.factory().notIfArray.add(new NotIfModel(messageBody));

        //FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Dashboard.class);

       // fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new NotIfFragment()).addToBackStack("").commit();
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_vems)
                .setContentTitle(getBaseContext().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());

        synchronized (notificationManager) {
            notificationManager.notify();
        }
```

Instead of using Dashboard in Intent I want to call fragment

Comment: its not possible to open directly fragment, you can call activity then after check this activity is call from push and then after push your fragment from activity.

Comment: you can open the fragment in your activity's `onStart()`

Comment: use broadcase reciever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we know Fragments are the sub part of Activity... So To show anything you have to call Activity and inside the activity you can replace or add the fragment to show notification.

**SO my advice to you is that call the the activity from MyFireBaceService and inside that activity you can show your fragment by replacing and adding.** :)

I hope it will help you

Comment: Welcome Rishabh Saxena  :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to start your base activity as usual which contains fragment in it and in the onCreate() method you can load the fragment .

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
       FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
       FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
                       fragmentManager.beginTransaction();


         // Activity was not launched with a menuFragment selected -- continue as //if this activity was opened from a launcher (for example)
         HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment ();
         fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, homeFragment );

}
```